# How to add icons on SharePoint Quick launch

Tags: 2013, jquery, quick-launch

We would like to add icons for each navigation list items

displayed on quick launch bar. Is there a way to do that using css or jquery.

We are using SharePoint 2013 team site with settle.master.

[image]

Comment: check this https://support.bind.pt/hc/en-us/articles/204448029-Customize-SharePoint-2013-and-Office-365-v2013-menu-with-icons

Comment: This only works for Bind Tuning themes i am not trying to implement any new themes for this project. Any other suggestions?